# "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler' while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to connect to Azure AD and Microsoft Graph to get user photo. I am using .NET 6 Razor Pages and this is my configuration in Program.cs

```
string[] initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

When I put a breakpoint here, I can see that it has `initialScopes` values which I set at appsettings.json

In my index.cshtml.cs, this is my code:

```
[Authorize]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    private readonly MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler _consentHandler;

    private string[] _graphScopes;

    public IndexModel(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, 
        MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler consentHandler, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        _consentHandler = consentHandler;

        // Capture the Scopes for Graph that were used in the original request for an Access token (AT) for MS Graph as
        // they'd be needed again when requesting a fresh AT for Graph during claims challenge processing
        _graphScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');


    }

    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {

    }        
}
```

But it fails at `app.Run();`. The error message is:

> "Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler'
> while attempting to activate

I did google on this and it says I need `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi` but I think I have already configured this.

Comment: Please make sure you have registered `app.UseAuthorization();` and 
`app.UseAuthentication();` service as well.

Comment: In addition to this, do you have `services.AddRazorPages()
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();` and `app.MapRazorPages();` middleware as well?

Comment: You can directly can do like this `services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => { var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder() .RequireAuthenticatedUser() .Build(); options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy)); }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();` Just after your  `.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`. You can [`get more details here in official sample`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/ca3427be6cd2139b65e17947b6bb70691d897abc/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/Startup.cs#L32)

Comment: So root cause of your error is missing out these services `services.AddControllersWithViews()
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();`